# Readback KeyValueMetadata from Field and Schema in pyarrow from file written in C++

Tags: parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

If I write a simple Parquet file using the script [simple-write-parquet.cpp](https://gist.github.com/dantrim/33f9f14d0b2d3ec45c022aa05f7a45ee), I expect to have a simple Parquet file with a single column `MyInt`. The script [simple-write-parquet.cpp](https://gist.github.com/dantrim/33f9f14d0b2d3ec45c022aa05f7a45ee) attempts to add `KeyValueMetadata` to the field `MyInt` with some dummy values. In the C++ code, if I do,

```cpp
std::cout << field->ToString(true) << std::endl;
```

I see the expected return.

```
...
-- metadata --
foo: bar
bar: foo
```

and I expect that this metadata will be preserved in the output Parquet file.

However, when I attempt to read this file back using `pyarrow`, this field metadata key-value pair does not seem to exist:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table = pq.read_table("test.parquet")
field = table.field("MyInt")
field.metadata # None!
```

Is there a way to retrieve from within `pyarrow` the `KeyValueMetadata` attached to both fields and schema (e.g. via the `WithMetadata` methods) from the C++ side writing out the Parquet files to disk?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the metadata isn't saved by default. Try to turn on `store_schema` on in the `ArrowWriterProperties`

```
void write_parquet_file(const arrow::Table& table)
{
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::FileOutputStream> outfile;
    PARQUET_ASSIGN_OR_THROW(outfile, arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open("test.parquet"));
    PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK(parquet::arrow::WriteTable(
        table,
        arrow::default_memory_pool(),
        outfile,
        3,
        parquet::default_writer_properties(),
        parquet::ArrowWriterProperties::Builder().store_schema()->build()));
}
```

It should work:

```
>>> table.field('MyInt').metadata
{b'PARQUET:field_id': b'1', b'bar': b'foo', b'foo': b'bar'}
```

Note that parquet also adds some metadata which you will have to filter out.

Comment: Perfect, this does just what I wanted -- thanks 0x26res